# A Lipschitz function is $C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I am wondering if a Lipschitz function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$, that is its derivative is also continuous? I have seen that in a text however I could not prove it and does not seem so obvious for me!

Any suggestion?

Comment: if $f$ is $C^1$, then by definition its derivative is continuous, regardless of the Lipschitz property.

Comment: Yes but what about the Lipschitz?

Comment: Are you asking if Lipschitz implies $C^1$ ?

Comment: No, it need not to be differentiable everywhere.

Comment: A Lipschitz function does not need to be differentiable and a differentiable Lipschitz function still doesn't need to have a continuous derivative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is negative. Take, for example, $f(x)=|x|$. Then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=||x|-|y||\le|x-y|
$$
and hence $f$ is Lipschitz. However, it is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: How about differentiable a.e.?

Comment: @TonyS.F. That's a good question. Actually, a Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable almost everywhere (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) for more details).